# Is it possible to change active record associations in memory without saving them to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We're using Ruby on Rails.  ActiveRecord with MySQL as database.

We have the association between order and order_items.  An order has 1 or more order_items.
So we can do the following (1029 is the order ID)

```
o=Order.find 1029
o.order_items
```

Is it possible to manipulate the active record association (for example, remove certain order items of the order) only in memory without saving the changes to the database?
If so, how would you do it?

We have a method that traverses an order's order-items, and if we can do the above, our life would be much easier.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you asked is possible. Just keep in mind that `o.order_items` will return an *array* of order_item instances. So you can use any method you'd like on this array. So sure, you can remove certain order_items just like you can remove certain elements from an array.

There are many ways to remove elements from an array. Some notable methods are `pop`, `drop`, `shift`, `compact`, `delete`, `uniq` etc. [Choose whichever methods that suit your needs here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html).

Comment: Performing changes to the association will trigger writes to the database... for instance: `o.order_items.delete some_order_item` will actually do a db update right then and there, without having to call `o.save`. Isn't the OP's question how to manipulate the association without db writes? What am I missing here?

Comment: `delete` method in my response is a method for array, which will only delete elements from the array. You can also change association between models without saving to database by manipulating the associations keys (and not saving the changes).

Comment: I believe you are wrong here. The `o.order_items` in the OP's question is clearly an example of obtaining an association. It's not merely an array. Deleting from it will delete from the DB.

Comment: You would want to do `o.order_items.to_a.delete` to guarantee that you're working with the array, not the association. Both`delete` and `uniq` have special meanings when called on an association.

Answer (score 0):

```
o=Order.find 1029,1030,1031,1032
o.order_items

o2=Order.find 1029
o2.order_items

o3 = o2-o1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest such way to delete AR object in memory.
Add an attribute to the appropriate model that is responsible for marking AR object as deleted (e.g. `deleted` attribute):

```
   class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
     ...
     attr_accessor :deleted

     def deleted
       @deleted || 'no'
     end
   end
```

Mark the appropriate object as deleted:

```
o.order_items {|oi| oi.deleted = 'yes' if oi.id == 1029}
```

Filter order_items set only not deleted rows:

```
o.order_items do |oi| 
 unless oi.deleted == 'yes'
 ...
 end
end
```